# Handle data from header in Onion Architecture in every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webapi

I have in the header some custom keys ( UserId, language_Id ) that need to filter the data.
I want these keys in the services project. but these keys exist in request only.

**What's the best way to make these keys in (the header) available in the services project ??**

My Solution Contains from projects:

- Web API -> Custom keys Header in Request.
- Entities
- Repository
- Services -> Need these keys to be available here.

Controller

```
public class ProductController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IProductServices _ProductServices;
    public ProductController(IProductServices ProductServices)
    {
        _ProductServices = ProductServices;
    }

    [HttpPost("GetList")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<BaseResponseDto<IQueryable<ProductDTO>>>> GetList(ProductsPagingReqestDTO requestDto)
    {
        Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues value = new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues();
        HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("languageid", out value);
        int userId = GetCurrentUserId();

        LanguageId = int.Parse(value);
        _ProductServices.LanguageId = LanguageId;

        return await _ProductServices.GetList(requestDto);
    }
```

The Service:

```
 public class ProductServices: IProductServices
{
    private readonly IRepository<Product> _productRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ProductServices(IRepository<Product> productRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _productRepository = productRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<BaseResponseDto<IQueryable<ProductDTO>>> GetList(ProductsPagingReqestDTO requestDto)
    {
         // Must get keys from headers to using it here !!! 
    }}
```

I think generic services handle the headers in every request and all services inherit from this generic service. How about that? Or any generic idea's to don't repeat me.

Comment: Have you tried IHttpContextAccessor? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0